# Can I specify what version of Java to run my program on

Tags: java, version

I have an old program that runs on `JRE 1.6`, when you upgrade beyond that the program will not log in.

I've looked into upgrading it but cant seem to make it compatible with later JRE versions. 
Problem is customers keep upgrading the `JRE` on the machine it runs on, even when told not to.

Is it possible to install 2 JRE on a machine and specify which one to use when running my program?

I was thinking if the class path points to JRE 1.8 but i didn't use the classpath but the full address of the JRE 1.6, would that work ?

Edit:

`java -Djava.library.path=lib/ -classpath .;lib/Serialio.jar;lib/log4j.jar;lib/client.jar -Djava.security.policy=java.policy 192.168.0.10 1098`

this is my bat file, i've tried replacing -classpath with C:\jre1.5/bin/java.exe -jar but it thinks thats the name of my main class not the new class path, what am i doing wrong

Comment: none, compiled using ant and run with a bat file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to install 2 JRE on a machine and specify which one to use when running my program?

**YES**, if you execute the jar, you can run it from an specific `JRE`

```
path_to_jre/bin/java.exe -jar YourApp.jar
```

Simply put the above line in a `.bat` file for your customers and double click will execute the program with defined java version, allowing your customers to upgrade java for other apps without problem.

---

> `java -Djava.library.path=lib/ -classpath .;lib/Serialio.jar;lib/log4j.jar;lib/client.jar -Djava.security.policy=java.policy 192.168.0.10 1098` is my bat file, i've tried replacing `-classpath` with `path_to_jre/bin/java.exe -jar` it thinks thats the name of my main class not the new class path, what am i doing wrong

your bat file must be something similar to this (path to java is my own one):

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java 
       -Djava.library.path=lib/ 
       -classpath .;lib/Serialio.jar;lib/log4j.jar;lib/client.jar 
       -Djava.security.policy=java.policy 192.168.0.10 1098
```

Comment: java -Djava.library.path=lib/  -classpath .;lib/Serialio.jar;lib/log4j.jar;lib/client.jar  -Djava.security.policy=java.policy  192.168.0.10 1098 is my bat file, i've tried replacing -classpath with path_to_jre/bin/java.exe -jar but it thinks thats the name of my main class not the new class path, what am i doing wrong

Comment: please, add extra info to the question to clarify, read code in comments is near impossible

Comment: also, `path_to_jre` must be replaced by real path i.e.: **c:\java\jre6\\***